# Mostrar los atributos de un producto siendo este un producto variable

Tags: php, html, woocommerce

Vengo a preguntar si alguien sabe la solución a mi problema. Resulta que tengo un código que muestra los atributos de un producto donde quiera (en este caso en la descripción corta). Lo que pasa es que los productos que tienen variaciones, me los muestra duplicados como si por cada variación hubieran los mismos atributos cuando realmente son solamente unos cuantos atributos para un producto.

El código empieza aquí:

```
    function ts_add_text_short_descr($description){
   global $product, $post;
if ( is_product() ){
$product_attributes = $product->get_attributes(); 
    ?>
    <div class="row custom_sttr">
    <?php
foreach($product_attributes as $pdata){
    
        $attribute_data = $pdata->get_data();
        if($attribute_data['visible'] ==1) {
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($pdata);
        $id = $attribute_data['id']; 
        $attr_icons = get_option( "wc_attribute_pa_css_icons-$id" );
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 col-6 col-sm-4 pattr_col">        
            <div class="attr_tit">
                <?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_data['name'] ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="attr_icons">
                <img class="attr_img" src="<?php echo $attr_icons; ?>"> <!-- Se cambio del tag i al tag img para poder usar flaticons en vez de fontawesome --> 
            </div>
            <?php $terms = get_terms($attribute_data['name']); 
                $terms =  wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), $attribute_data['name'] );
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) { //echo "<pre>"; print_r($term);  ?>
                    <div class="attr_terms">
                        <?php echo $term->name; ?>
                    </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php   } }  ?>
    </div>
```

El código termina aquí. Gracias de antemano por las respuestas.